# Angular JS ng-model array object

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using angular js, for some reason I am not able to hold array in a model.

Here's my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="dataObject.orientation_competency['57']" value="57" name="orientation_competency[]" rel="orientation" data-count="3" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="dataObject.orientation_competency['58']" value="58" name="orientation_competency[]" rel="orientation" data-count="3" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="dataObject.orientation_competency['59']" value="59" name="orientation_competency[]" rel="orientation" data-count="3" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

When I try to click on checkbox, its throwing an error:

> Error: Xa(...) is undefined
>   Ya.prototype.objectIndex/<.assign@http://soller.local/wp-content/themes/talentojo/web/js/v2/angular/angular.js:162
>   cehttp://soller.local/wp-content/themes/talentojo/web/js/v2/angular/angular.js:174
>   Lc.checkbox/http://soller.local/wp-content/themes/talentojo/web/js/v2/angular/angular.js:171
>   Bd/this.$gethttp://soller.local/wp-content/themes/talentojo/web/js/v2/angular/angular.js:102
>   Bd/this.$gethttp://soller.local/wp-content/themes/talentojo/web/js/v2/angular/angular.js:103
>   Lc.checkbox/<@http://soller.local/wp-content/themes/talentojo/web/js/v2/angular/angular.js:171
>   x.event.dispatch@http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5
>   x.event.add/y.handle@http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5
>
> http://soller.local/wp-content/themes/talentojo/web/js/v2/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.js
>   Line 84

Comment: Does `orientation_competency` define a property named `59` or is that an index?

Comment: basically its an ID of a database row, which needs to be passed, so its not an index

Comment: What does orientation_competency look like? The syntax you have there suggests that it's an object with properties called 57, 58 and 59.

Comment: '57' is the property or index.. if u want it as an index write 57 and not '57'